# Casting Byte to Byte error

Tags: casting, java-8

I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Byte; cannot be cast to java.lang.Byte
```

In a function that returns a generic `Byte`:

```
public void myFunction(ArrayList<Transition<Byte>> transitions){
    Transition<Byte> someObject = transitions.get(0);
    Byte [] actions = new Byte[1];
    actions[0] = someObject.getAction();
}
```

Why? Am I doing something blatantly obvious? These functions are part of a complex library and I don't feel like fiddling around with their implementations.

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Byte;` means `Byte[]`, i.e. an array of `Byte` objects.

Comment: Since there is no unchecked operation recognizable in this piece of code, that must have happened before silently. This situation is called *heap pollution*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is a bit hard to read because it uses the [binary name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) of the class. The binary name `[Ljava.lang.Byte;` actually means `java.lang.Byte[]`, i.e. an array of `Byte` objects which you tried to cast to `Byte` implicitly.

Under normal operations, the implicit casts of Generic code should never throw a `ClassCastException`, this kind of safety is the purpose of Generics. However, if *unchecked* operations are performed, this guaranty can get lost.

Since in your posted code, no unchecked operation is recognizable, the unchecked operation must have happened before without producing an exception, but leaving the program in an inconsistent state, undermining the Generic type safety. This situation is called *heap pollution*.

E.g., if the list actually contains `Transition<Byte[]>` instances and there was a type cast of that list to `ArrayList<Transition<Byte>>` before the invocation of your `myFunction` method, that type cast would proceed, because, due to *type erasure*, the correctness of the cast (regarding the element types) can’t be checked at runtime. That’s why you will get an “unchecked” warning at compile time when performing such a type cast.

So you have to search for the cause of the problem by looking for “unchecked” or “raw types” warnings and verify that these warnings are not turned off.